# Interpretation of 95 % CI

Tags: interpretation

Could you please help to understand if this interpretation for OR 1.318 and 95 % CI 0.72-2.42 is correct. Especially, I want to understand how we determine the positive or negative direction, do we focus on 1? whether it is included in CI or not?

the odds of depression among personnel who worked for more than 8 hours per day is 1.318 times the odds of those who worked per 8 hours a day, considering the range of observed effect from moderately negative to strongly positive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my understanding, the confidence intervals suggest the effect is not significant, as the CIs include 1. So the interpretation would be that working hours are not related to depression likelihood.